# Two Matrices with same Eigenvalue and Eigenvector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$, $B$ be two $2 \times 2$ matrices. Of course both matrices have the same eigenvalue and eigenvector if and only if $A = B$. But is there a simple condition that tells us when $A$ and $B$ share just one similar eigenvalue and eigenvector? Thanks!

Comment: Your "of course" is not true at all.  For example, $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 2\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ have the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: hint. sum of distinct eigenvalues equals to the sum of diagonal elements.

Comment: As to where this is going, look up Jordan Normal Form

Comment: @WillJagy But there's more to it than Jordan Normal Form if you want the eigenvector to be the same.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, sure. Just suggesting one direction to begin looking.